# How do I refresh data periodically in Android?

Tags: android

If I have used threads instead of an async task, then how do I refresh data periodically while navigating through activities?  My data is read and parsed in the main activity.

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity
  {
    //data_bedpres_future stores future data from current date
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data_bedpres_future = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

//data_bedpres_past stores past data from current date
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data_bedpres_past = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

//data_nyheter_future stores future data from current date
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data_nyheter_future = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

//data_nyheter_past stores past data from current date
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data_nyheter_past = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private ArrayList<Date> mydate = new ArrayList<Date>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ProgressBar progress_waiting1=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress1);
    progress_waiting1.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);


    final ProgressBar progress_waiting2=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress2);
    progress_waiting2.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

    Typeface tf_helvetica = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/HelveticaNw.ttf");
    Typeface tf_helvetica_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/HelveticaNwBd.ttf");

    Config.TF_HELVETICA=tf_helvetica;
    Config.TF_HELVETICA_BOLD=tf_helvetica_bold;



    final ImageButton bttn_bedpress=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bttn_bedpress);
    ImageButton bttn_news=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bttn_news);
    ImageButton bttn_logo=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bttn_logo);
    ImageButton bttn_faq=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bttn_faq);
    ImageButton bttn_cv=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bttn_cv);
    ImageButton bttn_omnu=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bttn_omnu);

    ImageButton bttn_recent=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    final RelativeLayout img_gray_bg=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.img_gray_bg);
    img_gray_bg.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

    final TextView txt_wait=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_wait);
    txt_wait.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);

    final TextView topheading=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_topheading);
        topheading.setTypeface(Config.TF_HELVETICA_BOLD);
    final TextView headline=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_headline);
        headline.setTypeface(Config.TF_HELVETICA_BOLD);
    final TextView date=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_date);
        date.setTypeface(Config.TF_HELVETICA_BOLD);
    final TextView txt_place=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_place);
        txt_place.setTypeface(Config.TF_HELVETICA_BOLD);
    final ImageView img_company=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_company);

    final TextView txt_news=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_news);
        txt_news.setTypeface(Config.TF_HELVETICA_BOLD);
    final TextView txt_career=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_career);
        txt_career.setTypeface(Config.TF_HELVETICA_BOLD);
    final TextView txt_bedpress=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_bedpress);
        txt_bedpress.setTypeface(Config.TF_HELVETICA_BOLD);

    final TextView txt_cv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_cv);
        txt_cv.setTypeface(Config.TF_HELVETICA_BOLD);
    final TextView txt_faq=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_faq);
        txt_faq.setTypeface(Config.TF_HELVETICA_BOLD);
    final TextView txt_logo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_logo);
        txt_logo.setTypeface(Config.TF_HELVETICA_BOLD);

    if(!HaveNetworkConnection())
    {
        Log.v("no network","no network");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Nettverk ikke tilgjengelig")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                   {
                       dialog.cancel(); 
                   }
               });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    final Thread parseThread=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run()
        {
            if(HaveNetworkConnection())
            {
                parseDataBedPres(Config.URL_BedPres);
                parseDataNyheter(Config.URL_Nyheter);
                Collections.sort(mydate);

            }
            else
            {
                Log.v("net not connected","net not connected");
                parseDataBedPresLocal();
                parseDataNyheterLocal();
                /*
                Looper.prepare();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Nettverk ikke tilgjengelig")
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                           {
                               dialog.cancel(); 
                           }
                       });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();*/
            }
        }
    });
    parseThread.start();

    Thread displayThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

         try
         {
             parseThread.join();
         }
         catch (InterruptedException e) 
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }  
         mHandler.post(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                progress_waiting1.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                progress_waiting2.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                txt_wait.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
                img_gray_bg.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);

                String month[]=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.month_array);

                if(data_bedpres_future.size()!=0)
                {
                    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    Date dt = null;
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    try
                    {
                        dt = df.parse(data_bedpres_future.get(1).get(0));
                        cal.setTime(dt);
                    }
                    catch (ParseException e1) 
                    {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    DateFormat df2=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
                    Date dt2 = null;
                    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    try
                    {
                        dt2 = df2.parse(data_bedpres_future.get(2).get(0));
                        cal2.setTime(dt2);
                    }
                    catch (ParseException e1) 
                    {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }



                    date.setText("Tid: "+cal.get(Calendar.DATE)+" "+month[cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)]+" kl "+cal2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+cal2.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

                    //date.setText("Tid : "+data_bedpres_future.get(1).get(0));
                    headline.setText("Neste Bed.pres: "+data_bedpres_future.get(0).get(0));
                    txt_place.setText("Sted: "+data_bedpres_future.get(3).get(0));
                    try 
                    {

                            Drawable img = drawable_from_url(data_bedpres_future.get(4).get(0),"icon");
                            if(img!=null)
                            {
                                int height,width,w;
                                height = img.getMinimumHeight() > 52 ? 52 :img.getMinimumHeight();
                                int ratio =  (((img.getMinimumHeight() - height)*100)/img.getMinimumHeight());
                                int wi    = (img.getMinimumWidth() * ratio) /100;
                                width = img.getMinimumWidth() -wi;
                                w=width;
                                int width1 = width > 211 ? 211 :width;
                                if (width>0) 
                                {
                                    ratio =  (((width - width1)*100)/width);
                                    int hi    = (height * ratio) /100;
                                    height = height -hi;
                                    w=width1;
                                }

                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = img_company.getLayoutParams();
                                params.height = height;
                                params.width = w;
                                img_company.setLayoutParams(params);
                                img_company.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable_from_url(data_bedpres_future.get(4).get(0),"icon"));
                            }

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else if(data_nyheter_future.size()!=0)
                {
                    date.setText(data_nyheter_future.get(2).get(0));
                    headline.setText("Siste nyhet: "+data_nyheter_future.get(3).get(0));    


                    try 
                    {
                        Drawable img = drawable_from_url(data_nyheter_future.get(0).get(0),"icon");
                        if(img!=null)
                        {
                            int height,width,w;
                            height = img.getMinimumHeight() > 52 ? 52 :img.getMinimumHeight();
                            int ratio =  (((img.getMinimumHeight() - height)*100)/img.getMinimumHeight());
                            int wi    = (img.getMinimumWidth() * ratio) /100;
                            width = img.getMinimumWidth() -wi;
                            w=width;
                            int width1 = width > 211 ? 211 :width;
                            if (width>0) 
                            {
                                ratio =  (((width - width1)*100)/width);
                                int hi    = (height * ratio) /100;
                                height = height -hi;
                                w=width1;
                            }

                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = img_company.getLayoutParams();
                            params.height = height;
                            params.width = w;
                            img_company.setLayoutParams(params);
                        img_company.setBackgroundDrawable(img);
                    } 
                    }catch (MalformedURLException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else if(data_nyheter_past.size()!=0)
                {
                    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    Date dt = null;
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    try
                    {
                        dt = df.parse(data_nyheter_past.get(2).get(0));
                        cal.setTime(dt);
                    }
                    catch (ParseException e1) 
                    {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    date.setText(""+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-"+month[cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)]+"-"+cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
                    headline.setText("Siste nyhet: "+data_nyheter_past.get(3).get(0));  

                    try 
                    {
                        Drawable img = drawable_from_url(data_nyheter_past.get(0).get(0),"icon");
                        if(img!=null)
                        {
                            int height,width,w;
                            height = img.getMinimumHeight() > 52 ? 52 :img.getMinimumHeight();
                            int ratio =  (((img.getMinimumHeight() - height)*100)/img.getMinimumHeight());
                            int wi    = (img.getMinimumWidth() * ratio) /100;
                            width = img.getMinimumWidth() -wi;
                            w=width;
                            int width1 = width > 211 ? 211 :width;
                            if (width>0) 
                            {
                                ratio =  (((width - width1)*100)/width);
                                int hi    = (height * ratio) /100;
                                height = height -hi;
                                w=width1;
                            }

                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = img_company.getLayoutParams();
                            params.height = height;
                            params.width = w;
                            img_company.setLayoutParams(params);
                        img_company.setBackgroundDrawable(img);
                    }
                    }
                    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        }
    });
    displayThread.start();  

    bttn_bedpress.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            //bttn_bedpress.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bedpres_pressed));
            if(data_bedpres_future.size()!=0)
            {
                Log.v("size of future data","size="+data_bedpres_future.size());
                startActivity(new Intent("com.vyam.BusinessPresentations"));
            }
            else
            {
                startActivity(new Intent("com.vyam.BusinessPresentationsPast"));
            }
        }
    });

    bttn_news.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(data_nyheter_future.size()!=0)
            {
                Log.v("size of future data","size="+data_nyheter_future.size());
                startActivity(new Intent("com.vyam.FutureNews"));
            }
            else
            {
                startActivity(new Intent("com.vyam.PastNews"));
            }
        }
    });

    bttn_logo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.vyam.CareerFair"));
        }
    });

    bttn_faq.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.vyam.FAQ"));
        }
    });

    bttn_cv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.vyam.CV"));
        }
    });

    bttn_omnu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.vyam.OmNU"));
        }
    });



    bttn_recent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent("com.vyam.NewsDetail");
            intent.putExtra("type","past");//it sends information that data must be shown from data_bedpres_past
            intent.putExtra("position",0);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

/**
 * the parseDataBedPres(String url)method does JSON parsing of  the url Config.URL_BedPres
 * @return void
 */ 

public void parseDataBedPres(String url)
{
    ArrayList<String> company_names_future = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> company_names_past = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> date_future = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> date_past = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> place_future = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> place_past = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> meeting_time_future = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> meeting_time_past = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> company_logo_future = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> company_logo_past = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> description_future = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> description_past = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> url_future = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> url_past = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> fb_id_future = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> fb_id_past = new ArrayList<String>();

    FileOutputStream fos=null;
    try {
        URL business_url = new URL(url);
        URLConnection tc = business_url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));


        StringBuffer fileData=new StringBuffer();

        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);
            Log.v("line"," "+line);

            fileData.append(line);

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) 
            {
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                try
                {
                    Date today = new Date();
                    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
                    //Date date = df.parse(jo.getString("meeting_date"));
                    StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder(jo.getString("meeting_date"));
                      s1.append(" ");
                      s1.append(jo.getString("meeting_time"));
                      Date date = df.parse(s1.toString());

                    if(today.after(date))
                    {
                        if(jo.getString("company_name")!=null)
                            company_names_past.add(jo.getString("company_name"));
                        else
                            company_names_past.add(" ");
                        if(jo.getString("meeting_date")!=null)
                            date_past.add(jo.getString("meeting_date"));
                        else
                            date_past.add(jo.getString(" "));
                        if(jo.getString("meeting_address")!=null)
                            place_past.add(jo.getString("meeting_address"));
                        else
                            place_past.add(" ");
                        if(jo.getString("meeting_time")!=null)
                            meeting_time_past.add(jo.getString("meeting_time"));
                        else
                            meeting_time_past.add(jo.getString(" "));
                        if(jo.getString("company_logo")!=null)
                            company_logo_past.add(jo.getString("company_logo"));
                        else
                            company_logo_past.add(jo.getString(" "));
                        if(jo.getString("description")!=null)
                            description_past.add(jo.getString("description"));
                        else
                            description_past.add(jo.getString(" "));
                        if(jo.getString("company_url")!=null)
                            url_past.add(jo.getString("company_url"));
                        else
                            url_past.add(jo.getString(" "));
                        if(jo.getString("fb_event_id")!=null)
                            fb_id_past.add(jo.getString("fb_event_id"));
                        else
                            fb_id_past.add(jo.getString(" "));
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        if(jo.getString("company_name")!=null)
                            company_names_future.add(jo.getString("company_name"));
                        else
                            company_names_future.add(" ");
                        if(jo.getString("meeting_date")!=null)
                            date_future.add(jo.getString("meeting_date"));
                        else
                            date_future.add(jo.getString(" "));
                        if(jo.getString("meeting_address")!=null)
                            place_future.add(jo.getString("meeting_address"));
                        else
                            place_past.add(" ");
                        if(jo.getString("meeting_time")!=null)
                            meeting_time_future.add(jo.getString("meeting_time"));
                        else
                            meeting_time_future.add(jo.getString(" "));
                        if(jo.getString("company_logo")!=null)
                            company_logo_future.add(jo.getString("company_logo"));
                        else
                            company_logo_future.add(jo.getString(" "));
                        if(jo.getString("description")!=null)
                            description_future.add(jo.getString("description"));
                        else
                            description_future.add(jo.getString(" "));
                        if(jo.getString("company_url")!=null)
                            url_future.add(jo.getString("company_url"));
                        else
                            url_future.add(jo.getString(" "));
                        if(jo.getString("fb_event_id")!=null)
                            fb_id_future.add(jo.getString("fb_event_id"));
                        else
                            fb_id_future.add(jo.getString(" "));

                    }
                }
                catch (ParseException e)
                {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

        writeInternalStoragePrivate("BedPres",fileData.toString().getBytes());
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (JSONException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    if(company_names_future.size()!=0)
    {
        data_bedpres_future.add(company_names_future);
        data_bedpres_future.add(date_future);
        data_bedpres_future.add(meeting_time_future);
        data_bedpres_future.add(place_future);
        data_bedpres_future.add(company_logo_future);
        data_bedpres_future.add(description_future);
        data_bedpres_future.add(url_future);
        data_bedpres_future.add(fb_id_future);
    }
    if(company_names_past.size()!=0)
    {
        data_bedpres_past.add(company_names_past);
        data_bedpres_past.add(date_past);
        data_bedpres_past.add(meeting_time_past);
        data_bedpres_past.add(place_past);
        data_bedpres_past.add(company_logo_past);
        data_bedpres_past.add(description_past);
        data_bedpres_past.add(url_past);
        data_bedpres_past.add(fb_id_past);
    }

    Log.v("hello files----"," "+getFilesDir().getPath());

}


/**
 * This parses the url for Nyheter
 * @param url
 * @return 
 */
public void parseDataNyheter(String url)
{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> image1_future = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> image1_past = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> image2_future = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> image2_past = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> date_future = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> date_past = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> headline_future = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> headline_past = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> ingress_text_future = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> ingress_text_past = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> body_text_future = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> body_text_past = new ArrayList<String>();
    //ArrayList<Date> mydate = new ArrayList<Date>();


    FileOutputStream fos=null;
    try {
        URL business_url = new URL(url);
        URLConnection tc = business_url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));

        StringBuffer fileData=new StringBuffer();

        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            fileData.append(line);

            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);
            Log.v("line"," "+line);

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) 
            {
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                try
                {
                    Date today = new Date();
                    Log.v("todays date","date--"+today);
                    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    Date date1 = df.parse(jo.getString("date"));
                    if(today.after(date1))
                    {
                        if(jo.getString("image_1")!=null)
                            image1_past.add(jo.getString("image_1"));
                        else
                            image1_past.add(" ");
                        if(jo.getString("image_2")!=null)
                            image2_past.add(jo.getString("image_2"));
                        else
                            image2_past.add(" ");
                        if(jo.getString("date")!=null)
                            date_past.add(jo.getString("date"));
                        else
                            date_past.add(" ");
                        if(jo.getString("headline")!=null)
                            headline_past.add(jo.getString("headline"));
                        else
                            ingress_text_past.add(" ");
                        if(jo.getString("ingress_text")!=null)
                            ingress_text_past.add(jo.getString("ingress_text"));
                        else
                            headline_past.add(" ");
                        if(jo.getString("body_text")!=null)
                            body_text_past.add(jo.getString("body_text"));
                        else
                            body_text_past.add(" ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(jo.getString("image_1")!=null)
                            image1_future.add(jo.getString("image_1"));
                        else
                            image1_future.add(" ");
                        if(jo.getString("image_2")!=null)
                            image2_future.add(jo.getString("image_2"));
                        else
                            image2_future.add(" ");
                        if(jo.getString("date")!=null)
                            date_future.add(jo.getString("date"));
                        else
                            date_future.add(" ");
                        if(jo.getString("headline")!=null)
                            headline_future.add(jo.getString("headline"));
                        else
                            headline_future.add(" ");
                        if(jo.getString("ingress_text")!=null)
                            ingress_text_future.add(jo.getString("ingress_text"));
                        else
                            ingress_text_future.add(" ");
                        if(jo.getString("body_text")!=null)
                            body_text_future.add(jo.getString("body_text"));
                        else
                            body_text_future.add(" ");
                    }
                }
                catch (ParseException e)
                {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

        writeInternalStoragePrivate("Nyheter.txt",fileData.toString().getBytes());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(headline_future.size()!=0)
    {
        data_nyheter_future.add(image1_future);
        data_nyheter_future.add(image2_future);
        data_nyheter_future.add(date_future);
        data_nyheter_future.add(headline_future);
        data_nyheter_future.add(ingress_text_future);
        data_nyheter_future.add(body_text_future);
    }
    if(headline_past.size()!=0)
    {
        data_nyheter_past.add(image1_past);
        data_nyheter_past.add(image2_past);
        data_nyheter_past.add(date_past);
        data_nyheter_past.add(headline_past);
        data_nyheter_past.add(ingress_text_past);
        data_nyheter_past.add(body_text_past);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the handler to call the same runnable obect for example when start the activity

```
handler.post(runnable,1000);
```

this will call the runnable after start the activity.

now in your runnable run method call same thing

like after 30 sec

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
       ........ ///do something
       handler.post(runnable,30000);
    }
}
```

this will call continuously until you don't remove the runnable from handler object

like this way

```
handler.removeCallback(runnable);
```

Comment: i came to an idea that on backpress onResume is called so can i implement the data to be loaded again on backpress

Comment: for that you have to override the backpress because default event is when you press the back button it'll finish your activity it is not similar to the home button like when press home button and open again your application it'll continue with the last stack

Comment: i have implemented it in onResume like following

Answer (score 0):

You may use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) it supports pereodical execution